# AngularJS : directive with ng-repeat and isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been trying to create a **directive** that takes the **content of the element and wraps it with an ng-repeat**. The trick is that the expressions in the content of the element have to be linked with the **isolated scope of the directive** (so I can't use ng-transclude).

I found a solution that seemed perfect:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874#issuecomment-46410994
But it doesn't work with an isolated scope which isn't satisfactory, I require an isolated scope in order not to pollute the parent scope.

In the following plnkr, you can try commenting line 10, and it will work.
http://plnkr.co/edit/B72H9Sd5Cs1Qc8GoTRGF

```
<test>
  <h3>- number: {{item}}</h3>
</test>

app.directive('test', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {}, // try commenting this line
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, tTransclude) {
      var children = tElement.children();

      var template = angular.element('<div ng-repeat="item in collection"></div>');
      template.append(children);

      tElement.html('');
      tElement.append(template);

      return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
        scope.collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      };
    }
  };
});
```

What I would like is the

#### - number: {{item}}

to be repeated for each collection item and the {{item}} expression to be linked with the isolated scope.

I don't understand the behavior. It seems to me like the {{item}} expression should be linked to the directive's scope (through the ng-repeat).
Instead, it's linked with the parent scope.

Could somebody please help me understand and fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: In the end, I was actually successful but I used a method that I don't find very clean (I manually compiled the directive)
http://plnkr.co/edit/pYEDQa8R31ZDVQFDbDcS

Comment: Oh and I found what I think is an even dirtier solution (in my opinion):
http://plnkr.co/edit/AiCiQtO44unq0d8hDBKa

Comment: Why was that not clear? The link phase runs after the compile phase of a directive. AngularJS directives are _compiled_ in the compile phase. You are defining a `link` function for your directive, thus it is running after the compile phase. Adding AngularJS directives to `element` in the link phase won't _compile_ them. So you _manually_ need to _compile_ them using `$compile`.

Comment: The "dirty" solution is actually less dirty. That `template` function you defined is called _before_ the compile phase, thus the `data-ng-repeat` directive is _compiled_ later in the compile phase, unlike when adding it in the linking phase.

Comment: Sergiu, I understand why I need to compile the directive in the solution I found, but I'm trying to make the "clean" solution work with an isolated scope.

Comment: And the only difference I can see between `my-repeat` and `ng-repeat` is that you need to declare `numbers` in your directive's scope, pretty bad thing to do IMHO. In other words, I don't really understand what this directive is supposed to do that is different than what `ng-repeat` already does.

Comment: There is a much more complicated use case behind it.

Comment: So the goal is not having to _manually_ use ng-repeat _and_ encapsulate the scope, right?

Comment: yes, and I eventually found solutions. I'm mostly interested in understanding why http://plnkr.co/edit/B72H9Sd5Cs1Qc8GoTRGF does not work with an isolated scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try [this fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/2fJdBR8qv42XgC9ZU5ak?p=preview) I added some stuff to:

```
app.directive('test', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {}, // try commenting this line
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, tTransclude) {
      var children = tElement.children();

      var template = angular.element('<test2>{{collection}}<div ng-repeat="item in collection" ></div></test2>');
      template.append(children);

      tElement.html('');
      tElement.append(template);

      return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
        scope.collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        console.log('test', scope);
      };
    }
  };
});

app.directive('test2', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    link: function($scope) {
      console.log('test2', $scope);
    }
  };
});
```

Basically when you add stuff to the DOM in `compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, tTransclude) {` that code executes before the linking phase (the code running in `return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {`.

If you look at the two `console.log` calls you'll see that `test2` occurs before `test`.

Couple this with an isolated scope on `test` and you end up with the scope in `test` being a child of the scope in `test2`. Counter-intuitive, I know, but it's the way AngularJS's compiling/linking phases work.
Thus `collection` is `undefined` in `test2` so `ng-repeat` has nothing to "repeat" on.

If you remove `scope: {}` you are basically telling `test`'s scope to be the same as `test2`'s (they are references to the same object), so `collection` will (eventually) be defined in all directives, including `ng-repeat`.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/z2krlO9TiEVpgjXfpntX?p=preview

Actually it looks like test and test2's isolated scopes are siblings.
But I guess what this means is that it's not directly possible to do what I want in that manner. So I'll keep to my other 2 solutions.

I should have thought of looking at scope ids to understand the issue. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Well, yes, they have different IDs because they are created with `$scope.$new` but they are not necessarily isolated: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new - prototypical inheritance is used.